# Swift 3 / Alamofire : I am not able to fetch the data on UITableView

Tags: uitableview, swift3, alamofire

I am using Alamofire and trying to fetch data on my tableview, however I am not able to get the data. When I use the cmd Print, its showing me the data but not able to fetch the data. How can I fetch the data on my tableview?

Please find the code below:-

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, NSURLConnectionDelegate {
//let myarray = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
var tableData = Array<Group>()

var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary



var group = [Group]()

@IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadGroups()
}

func loadGroups(){

    let testhappyhour:Group = Group(tempName: "TEST", tempID: "TESST", icons: "TEST", tempgbcount: "TEST")
    self.group.append(testhappyhour)

    //let groupQuery:String = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users"
    Alamofire.request("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").responseJSON
        { response in switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            let response = JSON as! NSArray
            for item in response { // loop through data items
                let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                let happyhour = Group(tempName:obj["NAME"] as! String, tempID:obj["id"] as! String, icons:obj["icon"] as! String, tempgbcount:obj["TOTAL"] as! String)
                self.group.append(happyhour)
            }
            self.tableview.reloadData()

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
}


func convertToArray(text: String) -> [Any]? {
    if let data = text.data(using: .utf8) {
        do {
            return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as? [Any]
        } catch {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
    return nil
}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    tableview.reloadData()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}




func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return myarray.count
    return arrRes.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell", for: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
   // cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.item]
    let cell : UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "groupCell")!
    var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = dict["NAME"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["TOTAL"] as? String
    return cell
}

}
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to change loadGroups function like this

```
func loadGroups(){

    let testhappyhour:Group = Group(tempName: "TEST", tempID: "TESST", icons: "TEST", tempgbcount: "TEST")
    self.group.append(testhappyhour)

    Alamofire.request("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users").responseJSON
        { response in switch response.result {
        case .success(let JSON):
            let response = JSON as! NSArray
            for item in response { // loop through data items
                let obj = item as! NSDictionary
                let happyhour = Group(tempName:obj["NAME"] as! String, tempID:obj["id"] as! String, icons:obj["icon"] as! String, tempgbcount:obj["TOTAL"] as! String)
                self.group.append(happyhour)
                self.arrRes.append(obj) // ADD THIS LINE
            }
            self.tableview.reloadData()

        case .failure(let error):
            print("Request failed with error: \(error)")
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it did work, however I am not able to get it the UILabel. I want it to display on the UILabel. And yea, thanks very much :)

Comment: you are talking about these labels ? cell.textLabel?.text = dict["NAME"] as? String
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dict["TOTAL"] as? String

Comment: i have a class file called GroupCellTableViewCell and I have connected my UILabels in there.

Comment: Hm ok then you can open a new question. Explaining the issue then I will be able to help.for now I am not fully aware,where issue can be.

Comment: Well , we can take this conversation on the chat

Comment: are you ok with it?

Comment: Ok, yes we can do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147886/discussion-between-sarah-malik-and-usama-sadiq).

Answer (score 0):

Array 'group' is appended with the Alamofire responses, but Array 'arrRes' is used as the table view data source. If you use self.group instead of arrRes in the data source methods, the table should update with the new groups received in the Alamofire response.